# How to check for the existence of deep subdomains even if the intermediate ones don't exist?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dns-zone, reverse-dns

Suppose that `test.example.com` don't exists and gives `NXDOMAIN` when runnning `dig` on it , but i know that `subdomain.test.example.com` exists and gives `NOERROR` when doing the same, is there a way to check that a deep subdomain exists even though the intermediate subdomain may not be there necessarily. Specifically, I'm looking for hints when probing or querying `subdomain.test.example.com` that points to the existance of the deep subdomain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose that test.example.com don't exists and gives NXDOMAIN when runnning dig on it , but i know that subdomain.test.example.com exists

This is not possible, per DNS specifications. Or said differently: it means the authoritative nameserver for this zone is broken.

See [RFC 8020: NXDOMAIN: There Really Is Nothing Underneath](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8020)

> When an iterative caching DNS resolver receives an NXDOMAIN response,
> it SHOULD store it in its cache and then all names and resource
> record sets (RRsets) at or below that node SHOULD be considered
> unreachable.  Subsequent queries for such names SHOULD elicit an
> NXDOMAIN response.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Patrick, but would like to provide some more clarity about what the actual expectations are:

If you have records at `subdomain.test.example.com` but none at `test.example.com`, that does not mean that `test.example.com` "does not exist", the term for this empty type of node is *empty non-terminal* (sometimes ENT).

When you query some name that is an empty non-terminal, the proper type of response is *not* `NXDOMAIN` (which would mean "there is no such name") but rather `NODATA` (which means "there are no records for the requested type", in the ENT case regardless which type you ask for).

For clarity, the `NODATA` response type is: response code `NOERROR`, `SOA` in the `AUTHORITY` section.

The indication that there *could* exist further sub-domains is that the response you got was not `NXDOMAIN`. If you also determine that there are no records at this name (ie, it is an empty non-terminal), there must be some subdomain (one or more levels down) where there actually is something.

The other aspect, which the question implies and Patrick covered is that some nameserver implementations are buggy and send `NXDOMAIN` even in situations where this is not the appropriate response.
That type of implementation flaw results in serving inconsistent data where what should all be a tree structure is actually broken into pieces that do not connect. That behavior particularly fails in the view of any resolver that relies on previously observed `NXDOMAIN` responses actually meaning something, as well as not being possible to represent in DNSSEC.

Comment: +1 to everything Håkan said :-) You can find examples of broken nameservers returning NXDOMAIN when they shouldn't at https://github.com/dns-violations/dns-violations/blob/4139e9dc2bbf5ff78cb673342f1258ef76fa8a10/2017/DVE-2017-0017.md and exactly on topic about NXDOMAIN vs NODATA in ENTs at https://github.com/dns-violations/dns-violations/blob/4139e9dc2bbf5ff78cb673342f1258ef76fa8a10/2019/DVE-2019-0001.md